# Inconsistent vertical line in table

Tags: tables, rules

I'm trying to recreate the attached table (left one). I managed to to create the right one with following code:

```
\begin{tabular}{c|cccc|c}
    \hline
    \backslashbox{$X_i$}{$Y_i$} &  $y_i$ & $y_2$ & $\ldots$ & $y_s$ & $\Sigma$\\
    \hline
    $x_i$ & $n_{11}$ & $n_{12}$ & $\ldots$ & $n_{1s}$ & $n_{1\cdot}$\\
    $x_2$ & $n_{21}$ & $n_{22}$ & $\ldots$ & $n_{2s}$ & $n_{2\cdot}$\\
    $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\ddots$ & $\vdots$ & $\ddots$\\
    $x_r$ & $n_{r1}$ & $n_{r2}$ & $\ldots$ & $n_{rs}$ & $n_{r\cdot}$\\
    \hline
    $\Sigma$ & $n_{\cdot1}$ & $n_{\cdot2}$ & $\ldots$ & $n_{\cdot s}$ & $n$\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

How can I make my vertical lines not cross horizontal lines?

[image]

Comment: Please, be so kind and convert your code sneped to full smal document beginning wit  `\documentclass{...}` used relevant packages and ending with `\end{document}`. It seems that instead `\hline`s you sould use rules from `booktabs` package. For test this idea, I need complete document ...

Comment: Please state how or where the macro `\backslashbox` is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use `\midrule` from the `booktabs` package.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c|cccc|c}
    \midrule
    \backslashbox{$X_i$}{$Y_i$} &  $y_i$ & $y_2$ & $\ldots$ & $y_s$ & $\Sigma$\\
    \midrule
    $x_i$ & $n_{11}$ & $n_{12}$ & $\ldots$ & $n_{1s}$ & $n_{1\cdot}$\\
    $x_2$ & $n_{21}$ & $n_{22}$ & $\ldots$ & $n_{2s}$ & $n_{2\cdot}$\\
    $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\ddots$ & $\vdots$ & $\ddots$\\
    $x_r$ & $n_{r1}$ & $n_{r2}$ & $\ldots$ & $n_{rs}$ & $n_{r\cdot}$\\
    \midrule
    $\Sigma$ & $n_{\cdot1}$ & $n_{\cdot2}$ & $\ldots$ & $n_{\cdot s}$ & $n$\\
    \midrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Yields:

[image]